# How to know the MAC and IP of my device?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, networking

The screen shot of my device looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Could anyone help me to know the MAC and IP Addresses please? My device runs Android ICS.

Comment: Can you see the values for MAC and IP addresses after connecting to a Wi-Fi? Obviously an IP address will be leased only after successful connection to a router with DHCP enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the MAC address from Settings > About > Hardware Information.
IP address will only appear on the page shown on your screenshot once you have connected to the wifi dhcp server.
Another way to find out IP is to use the browser and go to the website www.whatsmyip.org/ - this will tell you the address your router is on however, and not your local (wifi) network IP.

Answer (score 0):

Install this application, it may help you to get IP and MAC.

[Network Info II](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.networkInfoIi&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImF3cy5hcHBzLm5ldHdvcmtJbmZvSWkiXQ..)